# Proof about compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suposse $(X, \mathcal{T}_1)$ and  $(X, \mathcal{T}_2)$ are compact Hausdorff Spaces. Prove that either $\mathcal{T}_1= \mathcal{T}_2$  or $\mathcal{T}_1 \not\subset \mathcal{T}_2$ or $\mathcal{T}_2 \not\subset \mathcal{T}_1$.

**My idea:** Let $U \in \mathcal{T}_1$ then $X-U$ is closed in $\mathcal{T}_1$ and since $X$ is compact then $X-U$ is compact. But I don't know how to continue. I need an idea

Comment: Well, the negation of $\mathcal T_1=\mathcal T_2\lor \mathcal T_1\not\subset \mathcal T_2\lor \mathcal T_2\not\subset \mathcal T_1$ is $$\mathcal T_1\ne\mathcal T_2\land \mathcal T_1\subset \mathcal T_2\land \mathcal T_2\subset \mathcal T_1$$ which should be impossible for all sets (since $\subset$ is a partial order).

Comment: Suppose $\mathcal{T}_1 \subset \mathcal{T}_2$. Show that this implies $\mathcal{T}_2 \subset \mathcal{T}_1$. This is equivalent to the statement to be proved, but is much easier to work with.

Comment: HINT: Prove that if $\mathcal{T}_1\subseteq\mathcal{T}_2$, then $\mathcal{T}_1=\mathcal{T}_2$.

Comment: I think the conclusion is misstated (it is almost trivially true as it stands). A more interesting conclusion to be proved should read as follows. “Prove that either (i) $\mathcal T_1=\mathcal T_2$; or (ii) neither $\mathcal T_1$ nor $\mathcal T_2$ contains the other, that is, $\mathcal T_1\not\subset\mathcal T_2$ and $\mathcal T_2\not\subset\mathcal T_1$ both hold.”

Comment: @NoahSchweber Still: if $\mathcal T_1\not\subseteq\mathcal T_2$ is _not_ true (that is, $\mathcal T_1\subseteq\mathcal T_2$) and $\mathcal T_2\not\subseteq\mathcal T_1$ is _not_ true either (that is, $\mathcal T_2\subseteq\mathcal T_1$), then it is necessarily the case that $\mathcal T_1=\mathcal T_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$. We wish to show that $\mathcal{T}_2 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_1$. Taking your idea on board, let $U \in \mathcal{T}_2$, and hence $X \setminus U$ is compact with respect to $\mathcal{T}_2$.

Since $\mathcal{T}_1 \subseteq \mathcal{T}_2$, any open cover from $\mathcal{T}_1$ of $X \setminus U$ is also an open cover from $\mathcal{T}_2$. By compactness with respect to $\mathcal{T}_2$, such a cover has a finite subcover. Hence, $X \setminus U$ is compact with respect to $\mathcal{T}_1$. Thus $X \setminus U$ is closed with respect to $\mathcal{T}_1$, and so $U \in \mathcal{T}_1$.

Comment: You found a finite subcover of $X\setminus U$ with respect to $\mathcal T_2$. What guarantees that it is also a finite subcover with respect to $\mathcal T_1$?

Comment: The fact that the original open cover was with respect to $\mathcal{T}_1$. The subcover needs to be made up of the original open sets from $\mathcal{T}_1$.

Comment: Right. Thanks for clarifying. The only thing is that “Thus $U$ is closed” should be replaced with “Thus $X\setminus U$ is closed” in the last sentence. Otherwise, great answer. +1

Comment: Thank you!${}{}$

Answer (score 1):

As stated this is an exercise in basic logic. P or Q or R is equivalent to (not Q and not R) implies P.

Here not Q and not R means $\mathcal T_1 \subset \mathcal T_2$ And $\mathcal T_2 \subset \mathcal T_1$. Then this implies P.